# Tiny question about the design of database

Tags: database-design, stored-procedures

I got 3 items (hits, num_of_people, degree) to update while the people click 3 different buttons

And as you know, the SQL query are almost the same, just like:

```
update Mytable set XX = XX + 1 where ID = @ID
```

What I want to ask is that:

- Should I write 3 different stored procedures, 
  or
- Should I set a parameter that distinguishes these 3 process, maybe something like:

  ```
  if @flag = 'hits'  
  begin 
      ...
  end
  ```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write three different stored procs.

Firstly this is a more robust design over time - for instance, later when yours needs change slightly you can modify only the appropriate stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bind table or column names in SQL queries.  Binding is usually reserved for parameters like the ID value, not the name of the column.

With that said, I'd write three separate INSERT statements for each independent operation.  Whether or not you choose to implement them using stored procedures is your choice.